# rank of the product of 2 rectangular matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $m$ matrix, and $D$ be a $n$ by $n$ diagonal scaling matrix.

Is the rank of $A^T A$ always the same as $A^T D A$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  As an example, consider $D = \operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$. There exists a matrix $A$ such that $A \neq 0$, but $A^TDA = 0$.

If the diagonal entries of $D$ are all of the same sign (i.e. all positive or all negative), then we indeed find that $A^TDA$ has the same rank as $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a poof for this conclusion?

Comment: @HaoDong yes: take $B = |D|^{1/2}A$. Note that we have $A^TDA = B^TB$ in the positive case and $A^TDA = - B^TB$ in the negative case. $B$ has the same rank as $A$ and for any matrix $B$, $B^TB$ has the same rank as $B$.